# Another Domain for drupal stack exhange

Tags: discussion

I just landed up on a Drupal Answers-like site on a domain called stackfaq.net. Out of curiosity, do we have two domains?

Comment: That's not an SE site, it's an imposter. Don't log into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing [this whois information](http://whois.epik.com/STACKEXCHANGE.COM) with [this](http://whois.epik.com/STACKFAQ.COM), I would say it is not a Stack Exchange site, nor is it a domain handled by Stack Exchange, Inc. As Clive said, don't log in into that site, and report it to Stack Exchange.  To do this use the **Contact Us** link at the bottom of any SE site, and choose the **Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution** reason.

Comment: thanks @kiamlaluno, should I post it here http://meta.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: There is a question to report those sites, but I cannot find it. I am sure there is, since I happened to read it time ago.

Comment: I could not find the question, but I have informed SO team via mail.